# Does a sync() call blocks all write()/read()/fwrite()/... calls?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, system-calls

My application is a mutlithread (pthread) c/c++ application.

For some reasons, I've to call `sync()` from `unistd.h` (calling sync will block up to some secs)

An other Thread performs some file system operation. (fopen, fwrite, rename etc.)

What I've seen is that the file system operations are blocked for some time while the `sync()` command is running.

What are the reasons, why the other file system operations are blocked?
Sure - sync will sync buffers to disk. IMHO writes to file system are blocked while syncing. Correct?

What I'm interested in: What calls are blocked? File operations on same file system? All file operations? All functions based on Linux System Calls? What about write/read on devices like `/dev/ttyUSB0`?

Comment: [`sync`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sync.html) or [`fsync`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html) ?

Comment: `sync` as written

Comment: But I think question is similar for fsync

Comment: `sync` is global (all file descriptors across all file systems), while `fsync` is linked to a single file descriptor. So the potential impact of the latter is less. The exact behavior of these calls will depend on your kernel version and the file system (ext, xfs, ...), so providing that information in your question will probably improve the quality of the answers.